# Query by user, by month including a default value for not existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, my title looks a little bit weird but I could find a better way to title my question.

My current SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    ActionBy,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) AS 'dateStart',
    CONVERT(CHAR(3), (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0)), 100)  AS 'Month' , 
    YEAR(ActionCreateDate) AS 'YEAR',
    SUM([TimeTakenToComplete]) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    [myTable]
WHERE 
    [TimeTakenToComplete] IS NOT NULL 
    AND DeleteDate IS NULL 
    AND ActionBy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ActionBy, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0),
    YEAR(ActionCreateDate)
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) ASC
```

The end result looks something like this:

```
user1 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 1000
user2 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 998
user3 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 600
user1 , 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 , Jul , 2013 , 1110
user3 , 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 , Jul , 2013 , 2330
```

My problem is that I want to have a record for all users, for all months with a default value of 0.

So my desired result would look something like this:

```
user1 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 1000
user2 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 998
user3 , 2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 , Jun , 2013 , 600
user1 , 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 , Jul , 2013 , 1110
user2 , 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 , Jul , 2013 , 0
user3 , 2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 , Jul , 2013 , 2330
```

Is there any way that I can achieve this result or should I go and solve this issue programmatically?

Comment: using join with your table `user` is not an option..?

Comment: No, it cant be. You must examine your `WHERE` clause and make conditional `SUM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution out. It gives the desired output.

Also I have used table variables to simulate your need. I have also used `@Users` table to consider that you have a users table. If you do not want to use the users table then you can use `mytable` as well but there should be atleast 1 entry of the missing user for some other month.

```
--Simulation of your myTable
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    ActionBy VARCHAR(10),
    ActionCreateDate DATETIME,
    TimeTakenToComplete INT
)

--Simulation of users table
DECLARE @Users TABLE
(
    ActionBy VARCHAR(10)
)

--Dummy data for testing
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-06-01', 100);

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user2' , '2013-06-01', 100);

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-06-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-06-01', 100);


INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user1' , '2013-07-01', 100);

INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-07-01', 100);
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('user3' , '2013-07-01', 100);


INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('user1');
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('user2');
INSERT INTO @Users VALUES ('user3');

--Actual solution starts from here
; WITH MYCTE AS
(SELECT 
    ActionBy,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) AS 'dateStart',
    CONVERT(CHAR(3), (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0)), 100)  AS 'Month' , 
    YEAR(ActionCreateDate) AS 'YEAR',
    SUM([TimeTakenToComplete]) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    @myTable
WHERE 
    [TimeTakenToComplete] IS NOT NULL 
    --AND DeleteDate IS NULL --uncomment this on using with your code
    AND ActionBy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ActionBy, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0),
    YEAR(ActionCreateDate)
)

SELECT 
ISNULL(M1.ActionBy, L1.ActionBy) , 
ISNULL(M1.dateStart, L1.dateStart),
ISNULL(M1.Month, L1.Month),
ISNULL(M1.YEAR, L1.YEAR),
ISNULL(M1.TOTAL, 0)
FROM MYCTE M1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
    (SELECT DISTINCT [Month], dateStart, YEAR FROM MYCTE) m
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT ActionBy FROM @Users) U
    )
)L1
ON M1.[Month] = L1.[Month]
AND M1.ActionBy = L1.ActionBy
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

actually I was waiting for @Hamlet's solution..
but here is what I have in mind (I haven't tried to run it)..
and if there isn't any data in a month of any user, there will be no data at all (for that particular month)..

```
SELECT a.username,
    b.dateStart,
    b.Month , 
    b.YEAR,
    ISNULL(result.TOTAL,0)
FROM
(SELECT username FROM tableUser) a CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT dateStart, CONVERT(CHAR(3), dateStart, 100)  AS 'Month', 'YEAR' FROM result) b
LEFT JOIN result
ON a.username=result.ActionBy AND b.dateStart=result.dateStart
```

note: I called the table from your original query as `result`, and in your original query, you can just have this selection:

```
SELECT 
    ActionBy,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) AS 'dateStart', 
    YEAR(ActionCreateDate) AS 'YEAR',
    SUM([TimeTakenToComplete]) AS TOTAL
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to start with cross-joining all distinct values for users with all distinct values for months in the table, and then left-join the result to the table:

```
SELECT 
    c.ActionBy, m.mon, SUM(h.TimeTakenToComplete) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    (select distinct ActionBy from myTable) c
    cross join (select distinct dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) as mon from myTable) m
    left outer join myTable h 
    on h.ActionBy=c.ActionBy and dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0)=m.mon
WHERE 
    TimeTakenToComplete IS NOT NULL 
    AND DeleteDate IS NULL 
    AND ActionBy IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    c.ActionBy, m.mon
ORDER BY 
    m.mon ASC
```

Replace `(select distinct ActionBy from myTable)` with select on users table if any, and `(select distinct dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, ActionCreateDate), 0) as mon from myTable)` with a select on the Calendar table, if you have one.